# Why does this work (or how)?

Tags: variables, powershell, dynamic

In my email today I received an email about getting unused drive letters. [This was their solution](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/08/23/finding-unused-drive-letter.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage):

```
Get-ChildItem function:[d-z]: -Name | Where-Object {-not (Test-Path -Path $_)}
```

[PowerShell Magazine BrainTeaser had this for a solution, same thing.](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/01/12/find-an-unused-drive-letter/)

```
ls function:[d-z]: -n|?{!(test-path $_)}|random
```

I have no idea how `function:[d-z]:` works. I know that for each character between 'd' to 'z' is used but I don't know why the syntax works.

Testing `Get-ChildItem function:[d-a]: -Name` gives you an error saying `Get-ChildItem : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The specified wildcard pattern is not valid:[d-a]:`

So is that a dynamic parameter? How come is does not show up with `Get-Help gci -full`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`function:` is a PSDrive which exposes the set of functions defined in the current session.  PowerShell creates a function for each single letter drive, named as the letter followed by a colon.

So, `function:[d-z]:` lists the functions from "d:" through "z:"

`function:[d-a]:` doesn't work because , d-a isn't a range of letters.

Comment: Thanks. I never realized that `function:` was a PSDrive. Now that I understand it, I feel okay about using it.